# Independence of $n$ random variables

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be independent subsets of probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ (For every $I\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $P(\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j)=\prod_{j\in J}P(A_j) )$. Prove that $1_{A_1},1_{A_2},\ldots,1_{A_n}$ is independent, i.e. for every Borel set $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we have $P(\cap_{i=1}^n \{w\in \Omega: 1_{A_i}(w)\in B_i\} )= \prod_{i=1}^n P(\{w\in \Omega: 1_{A_1}(w)\in B_i\})$.

My partial answer:

Since $1_{A_i}(w) \in \{0,1\}$ for every $w\in \Omega$, then we have

$$
\{w\in \Omega: 1_{A_i}(w)\in B_i\}=\begin{cases} \emptyset & \text{if } 1\notin B_i \text{ and } 0\notin B_i ,\\ 
A_i & \text{if } 1\in B_i \text{ and } 0\notin B_i, \\ 
A_i^c & \text{if } 1\notin B_i \text{ and } 0\in B_i, \\
\mathbb{R} & \text{if } 1\in B_i \text{ and } 0\in B_i. \\  
\end{cases}
$$
First, we prove that if $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ is independent then $A_1^c,A_2^c,\ldots,A_n^c$ is independent. 
If there is $i_0$ such that $1\notin B_{i_0} \text{ and } 0\notin B_{i_0}$ then we have 
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{w\in \Omega: 1_{A_i}(w)\in B_i\} \right)= 0=\prod_{i=1}^n P(\{w\in \Omega: 1_{A_1}(w)\in B_i\}).$$ Hence, we can assume for the case $1\in B_i \text{ or  } 0\in B_i$ for every i.

Thanks.

Comment: $P(\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j)=\prod_{j\in J}P(A_j)$? Surely you mean $P(\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j)=\prod_{j\in J}P(A_j)$?

Comment: sory, typo bigcup and bigcap

Answer (score 1):

For every $i$, let $C_i=[\mathbf 1_{A_i}\in B_i]$. The goal is to show that 
$$
P\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^nC_i\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nP[C_i].
$$
Let us recall the, at first surprising but true, principle that *random variables are easier than events*, also formulated as *expectations are easier than probabilities*, thus, let us try to prove that
$$
E\left[X\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nE[\mathbf 1_{C_i}],\qquad X=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf 1_{C_i}.
$$
As you showed, for every $i$, $\mathbf 1_{C_i}=a_i\mathbf 1_{A_i}+b_i$ for some $a_i$ and $b_i$ in $\{0,1,-1\}$. Then,
$$
X=\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i\mathbf 1_{A_i}+b_i)=Q((\mathbf 1_{A_i})_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}),
$$
where $Q$ is the polynomial defined as
$$
Q((x_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n})=\prod_{i=1}^n(a_ix_i+b_i).
$$
There exists some coefficients $(q_I)_I$ indexed by the subsets $I$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that
$$
Q((x_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n})=\sum_Iq_Ix_I,\qquad x_I=\prod_{i\in I}x_i.
$$
When $x_i=\mathbf 1_{A_i}$ for every $i$, $x_I=\mathbf 1_{A_I}$ for every $I$, where $A_I=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i$. For each $I$, by the independence hypothesis of the events $(A_i)_i$, $E(\mathbf 1_{A_I})=\prod\limits_{i\in I}P[A_i]$.

Putting all these remarks together, one gets
$$
E[X]=\sum_Iq_I\prod\limits_{i\in I}P[A_i]=Q((P[A_i])_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}),
$$
and finally, simply by the definition of the polynomial $Q$, 
$$
E[X]=\prod_{i=1}^n(a_iP[A_i]+b_i)=\prod_{i=1}^nP[C_i].
$$